# A question about traceless matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$, be a set of $N$ vectors $x_i\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $\mathrm{span}\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N\}=\mathbb{C}^n$. Observe that the latter condition implies $N\geq n$. Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be Hermitian and such that
$$
x_i^*Ax_i=0, \text{ for all } i=1,2,\dots,N.
$$

Does this imply that $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

The trace is invariant under similarity transformations.
  That means we can assume that the matrix $A$ is in diagonal form and we have a regular matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that
  \begin{align*}
  0 = X_{:,k}^T A X_{:,k} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i X_{i,k}^2
  \end{align*}
  for $k=1,\ldots,n$.
  This is a linear system for $(\lambda_i)_{i=1,\ldots,n}$.

There are non-trivial solutions if the matrix $Y := (X_{k,i}^2)_{k,i}$ is singular.
  E.g., $X = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is Hermitian, we have

$$||A||_2=\max \{|x^{\star}Ax|: ||x||_2=1\}$$

Since $\mathrm{span}\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N\}=\mathbb{C}^n$ and $x_i^*Ax_i=0, \text{ for all } i=1,2,\dots,N,$ it follows that $A=0$.

Edit: my answer is nonsense. It does not follw that $A=0$

Comment: What about \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix} and $x_i=e_i$ in dimension 2?

Comment: Oooops ! You are right !